# What data structure(s) are appropriate for my situation?

Tags: c#, optimization, data-structures, dictionary

To start off, this is probably an XY problem, sorry about that.

I'm loading a file table from a file and placing it into an in-memory file tree.  Nodes in the tree represent a directory/file in the tree.  Currently, I'm using two data structures per node and that results in noticeable load times, due to inserting into collections, and higher memory usage, due to duplicating string data and referencing each node twice.  Trees are loaded once and are not mutated after that.

Every node has a List for accessing sorted child nodes and a Dictionary for accessing child nodes by name.  The list is lazily sorted for performance reasons.  SortedDictionary does not fit my use requirements because I need nodes with children be sorted above nodes without children, so passing an IComparer will not suffice.  When two nodes both have/don't have children, then they are sorted lexicographically (OrdinalIgnoreCase).

**Is there a data structure in .net which would fulfill my needs?**

**Additionally**, is there any way to provide a hash for the key when inserting to a Dictionary, and to later get a portion of a bucket from the Dictionary (ie: GetValuesByHash(int hashValue) yields all values whose corresponding key has the given hash)?  The file table which I am reading in already contains hash values for entire file paths (applicable to another thing I'm doing), and currently, the dictionary is just recalculating them for no reason.

I think I can hack together a solution by defining my own custom key which contains { Hash, Node } alongside a custom comparer, but that seems really ugly, and you wouldn't be able to get buckets of nodes sharing the same hash.  If anything, that would still feel like using the wrong data structure.

I have already googled "c# dictionary get hash" along with a few other queries, though at this point, I haven't' seen any similar questions.

Overall, looking for a data structure (probably related to a dictionary) with the following properties:

- ContainsKeyOfHash(), Get(hash): File Name Hash -> File Entry Descriptor(s)
- ContainsKey(), Get(key): File Name -> File Entry Descriptor
- Add(string fileName, Entry entry, int hash = gethash(fileName))
- Entries are sorted as follows:

  ```
      m_children.Sort(
         (a, b) => {
            bool aHasChildren = a.HasChildren;
            bool bHasChildren = b.HasChildren;
            if (aHasChildren && !bHasChildren)
               return 1;
            if (!aHasChildren && bHasChildren)
               return -1;
            else
               return -String.Compare(a.m_resourceName, b.m_resourceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
         }
      );
  ```
- All child nodes can be retrieved in the above sorted order.  Currently, I have a ChildrenSorted and ChildrenUnsorted property.  The ChildrenSorted property may have a performance hit due to sorting, while the ChildrenUnsorted property does not.

I think that at worse, my solution would be to write my own Dictionary-like class.  I don't have to remove keys from the dictionary, so it shouldn't be hard.  I sort of want to avoid doing that, though.

My node implementation can be viewed at: http://pastie.org/5547925

Thanks!

Comment: To achieve the "children sort" behaviour, you could use a `SortedList<string, Node>` where the `string` is not just the node's name but the node's name prefixed with e.g. `0` for has-children and `1` for doesn't-have-children. Then the sort order will be correct, and you can look up items by name by first trying `0TheName` and then `1TheName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is already pretty good. Here are some thoughts:

1. For a collection that is both sorted and has fast access by key, I can only think of tree data structures. You probably don't want a data structure that allocates one object per item. Probably you are served best by a kind of heap where all items sit in a single array. I think you can build that structure very efficiently by first sorting all children and then populating them (just like you are doing it now).
2. You might consider stuffing *all* data into a single such tree. That would save you most the per-node overhead (like collections which themselves have child-objects). The key would be the "path" to the node, stored in some efficient format. It could either be a path like `"d1\d2\filename"` or a `string[]`.

Point (2) would be how an RDBMS would do it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on #1?  I can't really understand the implementation, and thusly couldn't understand #2, which depends on #1.  Sorry for that - I haven't really touched stuff like this a lot before.

Comment: You can use trees to implement a collection that is both a dictionary and a sorted list. That allows you to find a child by name and to enumerate all children in a sorted way. Look into "C5 Powercollections" to get such a data structure. I don't remember its name but it is there (maybe IntervalHeap? I think that is in C5 and is an array-based tree which is nice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SortedDictionary` by simply put your `Sort()` lambda into an `IComparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer, IComparer<MyNode>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare(x as MyNode, y as MyNode);
    }

    public int Compare(MyNode x, MyNode y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        bool xHasChildren = x.HasChildren;
        bool yHasChildren = y.HasChildren;
        if (xHasChildren && !yHasChildren)
            return 1;
        if (!xHasChildren && yHasChildren)
            return -1;
        else
            return String.Compare(y.m_resourceName, x.m_resourceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow looking up nodes by name does it? (I may be wrong, but to use an `IComparer<Node>` `Node` has to be the _key_ type, right?)

Comment: Pretty sure Rawling's right, here.  I don't think I would be able to get a direct descendant of a given name with this implementation.